# How to get multiple data based on the getRecord with multiple Ids?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have multiple videos in custom metadata, I need to get all videos url in js, I am getting only record once I have put hardcode id but I need multiples records based on the Ids, I am getting all Ids but I am not getting the all values

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import getCMDID from "@salesforce/apex/VideoHandler.getVideoUrl";

const FIELDS = [
  "Video_Component__mdt.Video_URL__c",
  "Video_Component__mdt.Video_Title__c",
  "Video_Component__mdt.Video_Description__c"
];

export default class VideoComp extends LightningElement {
  @track cmdRecordId;
  @track videoUrl;
  @track videoTitle;
  @track videoDescription;
  tempVideoWithURL;

  @track allData;

  @wire(getCMDID) getCMDIDData({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.cmdRecordId = data;
      console.log(" ~ @wire ~   this.cmdRecordId", this.cmdRecordId);
    } else if (error) {
      console.log(" ~ @wire ~ error", error);
    }
  }

  @wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: "$cmdRecordId",
    fields: FIELDS
  })
  cmdRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].Video_URL__c) tempVideoWithURL.push(data[i]);
        else tempVideoWithURL.push(data[i]);
      }
      this.allData = data;
      console.log(
        " ~ @wire ~   this.allData",
        JSON.stringify(this.allData.fields)
      );
      //   this.videoUrl = this.allData.fields.Video_URL__c.value;
      //   this.videoTitle = this.allData.fields.Video_Title__c.value;
      //   this.videoDescription = this.allData.fields.Video_Description__c.value;
      //   console.log(" ~ @wire ~   this.videoUrl", this.videoUrl);
      //   console.log(" ~ @wire ~   this.videoTitle", this.videoTitle);
      //   console.log(
      //     " ~ @wire ~   this.videoDescription",
      //     this.videoDescription
      //   );
    } else if (error) {
      console.log("error::::", error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [getRecords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_records), not [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record).

```
import { getRecords } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

...

```
@wire(getRecords, 
  { records: [ { recordIds: '$cmdRecordId', fields: FIELDS } ] })
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: @RohitKumar The recordIds needs to be a list of ID values. Make sure you're using the correct values.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox

this is my apex code here...


`public with sharing class VideoHandler {
  @auraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<ID> getVideoUrl() {
    List<ID> result1 = new List<ID>();
    Map<String, Video_Component__mdt> mapCMDId = Video_Component__mdt.getAll();
    for (String result : mapCMDId.keySet()) {
      result1.add(mapCMDId.get(result).Id);
    }
    return result1;
  }
}
`

Comment: @RohitKumar Are you seeing any errors?